# How do I program this dice roller?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm trying to create a dice that rolls 5 times and takes the sum of those 5 values from 1 to 6. HOWEVER, if any of the values Is 2 or 5, the whole sum turns to zero. This is what I have so far.

```
def score(hand):
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    if roll == 2 or roll ==5:
        score = sum(roll * 6)
        print("("score") is 0")
    else:
        print("("sum") is your total")
```

Don't judge. Im trying :(

Comment: You forgot to ask a specific question, What went wrong with your code ?

Comment: What is `score = sum(roll * 6)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: if you are struggling with formatting your print statements, there are a couple of more or less equivalent ways. `print("score is {score}".format(score=score))` `print ("score is %s" % score)` `print("score is {}".format(score))`

Comment: @khelwood, I actually meant to put roll * 5 because I was trying to make the dice roll 5 times

Answer (score 1):

```
def f():
    l = [ random.randint(1,6) for i in range(6)]
    print(l)
    if (2 in l or 5 in l):
        return 0
    else:
        return sum(l)


f()
[2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1]
Out[120]: 
0
￼


f()
[3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3]
Out[121]: 
20
￼
```